# How do i mock RestTemplate exchange

Tags: spring, mockito

Trying the mocking as below :

```
Mockito.doReturn(responseEntity).when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), anyObject(), anyObject(), anyObject()));
```

this gave me a compilation issue:

"The method exchange(String, HttpMethod, HttpEntity, Class, Object[]) is ambiguous for the type RestTemplate"

so tried :

```
GetRelationshipInfoResponse relationship = getEntity();
        ResponseEntity<GetRelationshipInfoResponse> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<GetRelationshipInfoResponse>(relationship,
                HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        Mockito.doReturn(responseEntity).when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), Matchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), Matchers.<Class<Object>> any()));
```

I see in runtime now in `MethodInterceptorFilter`.intercept is getting null object value.

Can anybody suggest how can I fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to get such an error. I figured out a more reliable solution. I have mentioned the import statements too which have worked for me. The below piece of code perfectly mocks the rest template.

```
import org.mockito.Matchers; 
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;  
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;  
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
```

This is the actual template to mock.

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new Headers();
    headers.setExpires(10000L);     
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("dummyString", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    when(restTemplate.exchange( Matchers.anyString(), 
            Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
            Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(), 
            Matchers.<Class<String>> any())).thenReturn(responseEntity);
```

Here the 'responseEntity' value will not be null and we can use it to perfectly assert a statement.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to mock `RestTemplate`s. There is a framework designed for this exact reason: `@RestClientTest`

See here:

http://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/client/RestClientTest.html

Comment: sorry am not using spring-boot

Comment: This will not be testing the service at unit level. This will be more like integration (end-to-end) test which will spin the whole boot application.